# Latex: Decreasing the vertical margins in quote and verse

Tags: latex

In Latex, by using `begin{verse}` and `end{verse}`, there is about a 1-line space between the verse and the surrounding text (on the top and bottom of it). How do you change the amount of space here?

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: Yes it is, legitimised by many questions about TeX and LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its probably not the best way to do it, but this works.

In the preamble define a new environment called tightverse that moves the text up the height of a line before and after the verse environment.

```
\newenvironment{tightverse}
{\vspace{-1ex}\begin{verse}}
{\vspace{-1ex}\end{verse}}
```

Then in your document put your text within
\begin{tightverse} and 
    \end{tightverse} as usual.